# How to get the probability and label for each class?

Tags: python, pandas, list, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a model which classifies the venues based on some condition , It has 10 classes and I want that how much model predicts confidence score for each class ?

My code :
Result is an array in which model do predictions

```
        predictions=model.predict(result)
        confidence_score= model.predict_proba(list(result))
```

model.predict returns only a single value and confidence score has the list of scores for each class as shown below :

```
[[0.       0.14       0.       0.       0.       0.56       0.       0.17
  0.1      0.01       0.       0.20       0.       0.       0.002    0.01]]
```

It should return the class label also for each class that eg: Class A has the probability of occurring 0.2 % , etc.

```
labelencoder.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

Output should looks like :

```
{Class Label A : Probability score , Class Label B: Probability score ....}
```

---

Output comes using below code :

```
      dictionary=[dict(zip(labelencoder.classes_, cs)) for cs in confidence_score]

Output   
{Covent Garden': 0.0, 'London Cocktail Club - Liverpool Street': 0.0,
'Lost Society Battersea': 0.0, 'Lost Society Putney': 0.94.....}
```

In this case you can see that Lost Society has higher confidence score but when I do model.predict it return me some other label not this one , I have written in the code that predict the class which has highest score .

```
My code :
        predictions=model.predict(result) //returns the single number 
        confidence_score= model.predict_proba(list(result))

        dictionary=[dict(zip(labelencoder.classes_, cs)) for cs in confidence_score]
        print(dictionary)
            
        print("Recommended Venue for this type of category is",labelencoder.inverse_transform(predictions))
        print("Confidence Score : ", np.max(confidence_score))
        return labelencoder.inverse_transform(predictions),np.max(confidence_score)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want the dictionary that should return the probability score and its label for each class as shown above !

Comment: @Haseed  IIUC, we can't create a dictionary in this case because in case multiple predictions having the same predicted class then only last prediction will get stored in the dictionary as dictionary can not have duplicated keys.. May be you have to rethink your strategy on expected output

Comment: No , Multiple predictions don't have same class , They are unique ,

Comment: So you are only predicting one sample each time, right?

Comment: Yes , Exactly , You are right

Comment: The confidence score is giving me list of confidence scores for each class , I am not sure that which confidence score is of which class  , confidence score array is shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `zip` the `labelencoder.classes_` and `confidence_score` and pass the `zip` object to `dict` in order to create a dictionary

```
dict(zip(labelencoder.classes_, confidence_score.squeeze()))
```

In case you want to predict multiple samples in one go

```
[dict(zip(labelencoder.classes_, cs)) for cs in confidence_score]
```

Comment: It is just showing for a single class , I am getting output only {'Class A': 0.94}

Comment: How do You came to know that which confidence score belongs to which class ?

Comment: The `predict_prob` function will return estimates/probabilities for all classes which are `ordered by the label of classes` and so does the `labelencoder.classes_`

Comment: Ok  , Let me edit my question to you because one more issue is happening because of this line

Comment: Shubhan , I have edited the code , KIndly see and tell me that where issue is happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232329/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-haseeb).